# hyperref isn't linking the entire uri

Tags: hyperref, symbols

I am trying to create a clickable hyperlink using hyperref for a list of urls. One url is giving me trouble:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)

The relevant line of latex is:

```
\hyperref[ref6]{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function\_(mathematics)}
```

The line is clickable in the resultant PDF, but it only links to:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function

with the _(mathematics) part ignored.

I expect that this calls for some special escaping, but have tried several different approaches to no avail (backslashes and the like) and would appreciate some assistance.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Here's what's broke:

\hyperref[ref6]{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function\_(mathematics)}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  BTW thanks for providing a MWE. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\href` for this:

```
\href[options]{URL}{text}
```

The *text* is made a hyperlink to the *URL*; this must be a full URL (relative to the base URL, if that is defined). The special characters `#` and `˜` do not need to be escaped in any way (from `hyperref` manual, page 15).

Or use `\url`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Here's what's broke:

\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)}

\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)}{ref6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that you can use `_` and no need of `\_`.

By default, `\url` uses type writer fonts. To get url in roman font add `\urlstyle{rm}` in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{rm}     %% <--------- default is \urlstyle{tt}
\begin{document}
'
'
'
```

Comment: `\url` worked, but it's not in the same font as `\hyperref` or `\href`, is there a way to get the full url displayed in roman font?

Comment: @decuser Add `\urlstyle{rm}` in your preamble (say before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that `\urlstyle` is honored? When I also use `\usepackage{apacite}`, the urlstyle doesn't seem to hold and it is printed in the default typewriter font.

Comment: @WillSenn Try putting `\urlstyle` after `\usepackage{apacite}`. Just a guess, in the absence of your code for this.  May be you can ask a new question with the code.